# Liquibase CONSTRAINT for NotNull values

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

ALTER TABLE apple_member
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_banana_member UNIQUE (banana_id, apple_id)
WHERE banana_id IS NOT NULL

I want to add unique constraint only for not null values but i get syntax error:

Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. [Failed SQL: (156) ALTER TABLE apple_member
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_banana_member UNIQUE (banana_id, apple_id)
WHERE banana_id IS NOT NULL]

I really don't know what else I can do.

Purpose:
add the cosntratint for not null values

Comment: What database are you using? Looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the SQL Standard does not allow you to add a formal constraint for a subset of the rows. However, you can use an index to impose this restriction.

For example:

```
create unique index ix1 on apple_member (banana_id, apple_id)
where banana_id is not null
```